# Interact with an Array from another method?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a method that displays the information from my arrays. I want to have another method where I can add information to those arrays. You can see in the code how I am trying to do this. I am trying to use the addTV() method to create a TV and put it in the array which is in displayTVs().

```
package harveynorman;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by tiern on 11/06/2017.
 */
public class HarveyNorman
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        displayTVs();
    }

    public static void addTV()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the product code: ");
        String productCode = scanner.nextLine();

       if (productCode.startsWith("UE")) {
            modelNo.add(productCode);
       }

    }

    public static void displayTVs()
    {
        String[] modelNo = new String[]{"UE43MU5500", "UE49MU6200", "UE50MU6100", "UE55MU6100", "UE55MU6200", "UE55MU6500", "UE55MU7000", "UE55MU9000", "UE65MU6100", "UE65MU6100"};
        int[] quantity = new int[] {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2};
        int[] price = new int[] {729, 949, 929, 1079, 1199, 1299, 1739, 2394, 2399, 2759};
        String[] location = new String[] {"Opposite Samsung Stand", "Samsung Stand", "6th from Left, Bottom Row", "Top Row, 2nd from Right", "Top Row, Second from Left", "N/A", "Samsung Stand", "Samsung Stand", "N/A", "N/A"};


        System.out.print("SAMSUNG TVS");
        System.out.println("--------------------");

        for (int i = 0; i<modelNo.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+1 + ":\t" + "Model No:\t" + modelNo[i] + ".\tIn stock: " + quantity[i] + ".\t€ " + price[i] + "\tLocation:\t" + location[i] + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your simplest option is to pass the same mutable `List` object to the two methods. One option is to define the List of televisions in the main() method. If you're not allowed to use a `List`, pass a fixed-size array to the two methods, and handle overflow. Also, you'll have to call addTV() somewhere.

Comment: Well, I'd start by creating a `Television` class an have a `Television[]` rather than four separate arrays. I'd then probably *return* that from `displayTVs`. I'd then consider using a list instead of an array.

Comment: @JonSkeet I appreciate the help but I am fairly new to Java and not really experienced in using classes.

Comment: If your teacher has not yet introduced Java classes, you can pass four parallel fixed-size arrays or flexible-sized Lists down to each method. *[Side-comment - although I know of at least one university that is leaving object-oriented concepts until a second course, this seems like a mistake to me.]*

Comment: Or have them as static fields. Not ideal, but then neither is having multiple parallel arrays :(

Comment: @AndyThomas Could you show me a quick example of that if its not too much trouble?

Comment: @JonSkeet I did try that and it didnt seem to work

Comment: So show what you've tried, and explain what happened. We can't help to diagnose problems in code we can't see.

Comment: You can pass arguments to methods by including them, comma-separated, between the '()'. One thing you can pass is a reference to an array. For example, `addTV( modelNo, quantity, price, location )`. Or, if you can have a Television class and a television List/array, `addTV( televisions )`. It's up to you to write the rest.

Comment: @JonSkeet https://pastebin.com/vGxajySX

Comment: You're trying to declare a static field *in a method*. Fields aren't declared in methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet  https://pastebin.com/vW2qRt7H

Comment: Right, so that should be *in the question*, along with what goes wrong when you try to use it. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and bear in mind that the aim of Stack Overflow is *not* to be an interactive debugging service - it's to create a repository of high quality questions and answers.

Answer (score 4):

`Array`s in Java have a fixed size. Without copying them over in another, larger array its not that easy to just append another item into the array.

You can use Java List's to solve this.

a `ArrayList<String>` stores as many Strings as you wish (depending of the available memory - but that should not bother you)

---

The easiest way to solve your problem would be to your variables (`modelNo`, `location`, `quantity` and `price`) static `class variables`¹ of your class.

and change their types from Array to List types (`String[]` -> `ArrayList<String>`)

**This will result in not-so-clean code.**

---

A nicer solution would be to remove the static keyword from everyone of your methods except the main method.

in your main, create a instance of your class and call the methods on this instance. like:

```
HarveyNorman myClassInstance = new HarveyNorman();
myClassInstance.displayTVs();
```

then move your variables out of the method as `member variables`¹.

---

Another approach, to make your code more organized and better readable:

Create a new class for your TV-stock's with member variables for modelNo, quantity, price, location. (Or for TV's in general, depends a bit on you)

and then use a List of this class instead 4 separate Arrays for your data.

---

¹ :

```
class MyClass{
    static int a;       // class variable
    int b;              // member variable

    static void foo(){} // class method        
    void foo(){}        // member method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add anything to those arrays from a different method for 2 reasons.

1. They are local to the method displaysTv (means they can only be accessed through there)
2. Arrays cannot be resized. If you want to add dynamically to an array you need to use ArrayList or at least set a size for the array.

To explain my second point further the problem with your arrays is that you have already set their size and the values to go inside them when you placed the values in them on creation. If you want to add more you simply can't.

To answer your question use ArrayList, this way you can add as many records as you want. However do not declare those ArrayList inside of the method, declare them outside to have them as instance variables which are accessible by all methods within the class.

I have re-wrote your code so it would do what you want if you are stuck on anything let me know.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by tiern on 11/06/2017.
 */
public class HarveyNorman {

    private static ArrayList<String> modelNo = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Integer> price = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<String> location = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        displayTVs();
    }

    public static void addTV()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the product code: ");
        String productCode = scanner.nextLine();

       if (productCode.startsWith("UE")) {
            modelNo.add(productCode);
       }

    }

    public static void displayTVs() {


        String[] modelNoRecords = new String[]{"UE43MU5500", "UE49MU6200", "UE50MU6100", "UE55MU6100", "UE55MU6200", "UE55MU6500", "UE55MU7000", "UE55MU9000", "UE65MU6100", "UE65MU6100"};
        modelNo.addAll(Arrays.asList(modelNoRecords));
        Integer[] quantityRecords = new Integer[] {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2};
        quantity.addAll(Arrays.asList(quantityRecords));
        Integer[] priceRecords   = new Integer[] {729, 949, 929, 1079, 1199, 1299, 1739, 2394, 2399, 2759};
        price.addAll(Arrays.asList(priceRecords));
        String[] locationRecords = new String[] {"Opposite Samsung Stand", "Samsung Stand", "6th from Left, Bottom Row", "Top Row, 2nd from Right", "Top Row, Second from Left", "N/A", "Samsung Stand", "Samsung Stand", "N/A", "N/A"};
        location.addAll(Arrays.asList(locationRecords));

        System.out.print("SAMSUNG TVS");
        System.out.println("--------------------");

        for (int i = 0; i<modelNo.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i+1 + ":\t" + "Model No:\t" + modelNo.get(i) + ".\tIn stock: " + quantity.get(i) + ".\t€ " + price.get(i) + "\tLocation:\t" + location.get(i) + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndyThomas Edited

Comment: The edit provides an answer. That said, it can be harmful to do the student's work for him or her. It invites plagiarism, which may hinder the learning and endanger enrollment. There's a middle ground which helps the student overcome an obstacle, but still requires the student to write the code.

Comment: See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).